# NodeMCU custom built firmware http.get fails with a code of -1

Tags: lua, esp8266, nodemcu

I recently got a NodeMCU toolchain working with  https://github.com/slaff/esp8266.dev.box, but when I try to do a http.get, it immediately fails with the code -1, even though with the firmware from https://nodemcu-build.com/ it works fine. The heap space is approximately the same for both firmwares, and with both the custom built firmware and the cloud built one it works with a different URL.

The URL it is not working with is private, but overall it links to a google sheet and gets a CSV file. It still fails even when the CSV file is a single '0', and succeeds with a URL that links to a .txt file with around 20 characters.

Example url it doesn't work on:
[https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d//pub?output=csv&gid=0&single=true&gridlines=false&chrome=false](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/%3Cprivate%3E/pub?output=csv&gid=0&single=true&gridlines=false&chrome=false)

My user_modules.h from when I build:
http://pastebin.com/1LbxmS2B

My user_config.h:
http://pastebin.com/qBixhqyC

My Lua code (runs after I've successfully connected to wifi):

```
http.get(url, nil, function(code, data)
  print(code, data)
end)
```

Is there something that I am doing wrong when I build the firmware? Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: How should we tell? You don't show us Lua code. You don't show us with which config you built NodeMCU. And you seem to be comparing apples and oranges ("with the custom built firmware it works with a different url")?

Comment: Let me try to clarify. With the firmware from nodemcu-build.com, both urls work. With my custom firmware, running the exact same code, it fails on one url. I am updating the question with some code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `user_config.h` doesn't enable SSL-support (line 67), it's off by default.

Comment: Worked perfectly. How would I go about compiling the pair of binaries I get into a single one like from your cloud builder?

Comment: Use `srec_cat` to combine two binaries into one. Have a look at how my Docker image does that: https://github.com/marcelstoer/docker-nodemcu-build/blob/master/Dockerfile#L41